# Laravel - Rewriting this SQL Query using relations

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

> Disclaimer :  I'm an absolute newbie in SQL in general.

I have 2 tables with a many-to-many relationship, and thus I created a pivot table.

The tables are as follow : *sheets*, *styles*, and *sheet_style*.

- My `Sheet` model has a `styles()` method (`BelongsToMany` relationship)
- My `Style` model has a `sheets()` method (`BelongsToMany` relationship)

I'm currently trying to write a request that, for 1 given *style* name, it would retrieve the corresponding *sheets*.

Here is what I came up with :

```
protected function getSheetsFromStyle($style_name) {
    $style = Style::where('name', $style_name)->first();

    if($style != null) {
        $entries = \DB::table('sheet_style')->where('style_id', $style->id)->get();

        $corresp_sheet_ids = [];
        foreach($entries as $entry) {
            array_push($corresp_sheet_ids, $entry->sheet_id);
        }

        $corresp_sheets = [];
        foreach($corresp_sheet_ids as $s_id) {
            array_push($corresp_sheets, Sheet::where('id', $s_id)->first());
        }
        return $corresp_sheets;
    }
    return [];
}
```

However, this seems really *"unoptimized"*. Is there a way to achieve this in MySQL only, without having to create `foreach` loops everywhere ? Or maybe is there a way to use the relations I set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding completely, you can bring all of this down to just two lines if your relations have been set properly:

```
$style = Style::where('name', $style_name)->first();
return $style ? $style->sheets : [];
```

There's absolutely no need of looping twice to find sheets - that's exactly what the relations are for! :)

Comment: When I said I was a total newbie, I didn't lie :P Thanks a lot, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested, the SQL for solving this would be something like this :)

```
select sh.sheet_id, sh.sheet_name from sheet sh
join sheet_style ss on (ss.sheet_id = sh.sheet_id)
join style st on (ss.style_id = st.style_id)
where st.style_name = 'style_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

App/Sheet

```
public function Style()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Style');
}
```

App/Style

```
public function Sheet()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sheet');
}
```

Controller

```
use App/Style

protected function getSheetsFromStyle($style_name,Style $style) {
    $getStyles = $style->with('Sheet')->where('name', $style_name)
                       ->get();
    dd($getStyles);
}
```